# Xamarin App Not Running With AndroidManifest.xml DEFAULT code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

If this question I'm about to ask has a simple answer I apologize but I'll dive right in. I've been watching videos about how to get an Xamarin app to take pictures with xam.plugin.media. All the videos used the following TakePhotAsync method:

```
        // Attempt to get the picture.
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync( new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Rear,
            Directory = "Xamarin",
            SaveToAlbum = true
        });
```

Doing so actually makes the app I'm trying to create throw an error which is:

> Unable to get file location. This most likely means that the file provider information is not set in your Android Manifest file. Please check documentation on how to set this up in your project.

I go back and do more research and found out NONE of the tutorials told me I needed to edit the AndroidManifest.xml file and also add in a file_paths.xml file.

Now here's the real trouble. I copied and pasted the AndroidManifest.xml code from the github link [HERE](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin). But I made a couple SLIGHT edits, like to the authorities line. Code below:

```
  <application android:label="bugapp">

<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
          android:authorities="com.companyname.bugapp.fileprovider" 
          android:exported="false" 
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
             android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

At this point, the app does NOT launch at ALL. Nothing. I hit "start debugging" in VS 2019 and all I get is:

> Deployment was successful to Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
> ========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

However if I take out the code sample from AndroidManifest.xml completely the program RUNS, I can go ahead and click the button I have set up in the app. But if I leave it in, nothing, no app pops up in the VS 2019 emulator or even if I try running it on my own phone. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you read the important note here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#update-novemeber-2020

Comment: I'll give the link another read I guess. Not sure what I might of missed.

Comment: that the entire library has been deprecated in favor of Xamarin Essentials

Comment: Xamarin Esssientials huh? With media picker like the guy in this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYfGxhEHiec&t=758s&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis If so, I understand, because I followed this exact tutorial a while ago today and it worked. Problem was I couldn't mess with the picture taken with CapturePhotoAsync as you can see in the video at10:31. Even he says it only allows you to specify title. If that's the case it looks like I'll have to find another way to do whatever I need to do with the image. Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: Have you download the source file from the link below? https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin Does it still not work?

Comment: I guess the `file_paths` is auto generated & changes for the media nugget u usings are auto added to manifest, im not sure its being a long time i worked with them... Show your original manifest before you tried to copy paste, maybe we can help you rebuild it